# Symfony generate incorrect url with double /

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

I'm working on a symfony3 project, and i'm stuck with a problem,

We are sending emails that are twig based, with a button that has a link to our platform.

[Button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzw44.png)

And the open document button link is the following one:

*app.example.com/books/bookId/pageId*

Which is generated through **twig**:

```
url("open_book", { bookId: book_id, pageId: page_id })
```

And the url is defined on a controller file, with annotations

```
@Route("/book/{bookId}/{pageId}", name="open_book")
```

So, the link that user gets on the email, is the original, but with double // before books, like this:

app.example.com//books/bookId/pageId

I'm working on last twig version, and I don't know if it can be symfony issue either, since its only happening on our prod environments (it works on local, yey)

If it helps, our **routing.yml**

```
app:
    resource: "@BooksBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     app.%host%
```

This is only happening with urls that are generated by twig. We are using jms translation and jms i18n bundles also, so I thought maybe its trying to set a null locale betwen / / like:

app.example.com/en/books/bookId/pageId

But instead of en, an empty language maybe.

Any idea to start with?

**UPDATE 3/01/18**
Hey! Thanks for all answers. It seems that was a problem with symfony configuration at the end...

On file **parameters.yml**:

```
router.request_context.scheme: '%env(ROUTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SCHEME)%'
router.request_context.host: '%env(ROUTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_HOST)%'
router.request_context.base_url: '%env(ROUTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_BASE_URL)%'
```

Then our value for base_url was /. Seems that was the real problem. Removing / on that param does the trick.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are the emails generated by a command?

Comment: Seems that was a symfony problem. Updated my post with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For every route in the controller you are using prefix `/`:

```
app:
    resource: "@BooksBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    host:     app.%host%
```

This means that every route like:

```
@Route("/book/{bookId}/{pageId}", name="open_book")
```

Will be prefixed with `/`. In the end this route path will be `//book/{bookId}/{pageId}`. Some libraries truncate path values, the other ones not.

So just remove `prefix` parameter completly or declare route's path without leading slash:

```
@Route("book/{bookId}/{pageId}", name="open_book")
```

Comment: Close, but at the end it seems that the routing problem was on parameters.yml. Anyway, your approach help me to get close to solution, so, thank you a lot.

Answer (score -2):

try to replace this line

```
  url("open_book", { bookId: book_id, pageId: page_id })
```

By

```
  url("open_book", { bookId: book_id, pageId: page_id }) | replace({'//': "/"})
```

OR

```
{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost }} {{ path("open_book", { bookId: book_id, pageId: page_id }) }}
```

Comment: That does not look like a solid solution for the problem, but rather putting a patch onto it